# I cannot for the life of me figure out why my picture is not displaying correctly

Tags: android, xml, image, layout, imageview

I have an `ImageView` that I set to center inside the `LinearLayout` of a basic page in my `xml` file.  I snap a photo, detect for faces and display it on my `ImageView`.  The problem is, it always displays on the left side of my phone (I have the app permanently set to `portrait` mode)...I want the `width` to be  `fill_parent` and I want the `height` to be fixed, but any change I make does nothing to how it is displayed.

Here is my `xml` code:

```
<ImageButton 
     android:id="@+id/YesButtonTitle" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:background="@drawable/yesface"  
     android:layout_gravity="top|center" />

<ImageView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/image_view"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

<TextView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/message"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:padding="10dip"/>

 <Button
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:textStyle="bold" 
     android:id="@+id/action_button" 
     android:selectAllOnFocus="false" 
     android:layout_height="100dip" 
     android:text="Click here to crop detected face"/>
```

Here is where I set the `bitmap` to the `ImageView`:

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.action_button))
        .setOnClickListener(btnClick);
 mTheMessage.setText(R.string.faceMessage);
mThePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
mThePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap565);
```

`bitmap565` is defined as:

```
Bitmap bitmap565 = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565);
```

then compressed:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
    bitmap565.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Before I display the `bmp` on the `ImageView`.  Anyone have any ideas why it will not behave and will the `ImageView` correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, maybe it will work for you as well.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_id"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:scaleType="centerInside"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

As to why it your xml doesn't work. I looked and everything seems fine except maybe for the android:gravity that seems to do nothing in the case of images.

Comment: Still the same result...I seem to be able to do whatever I want to the xml file, it still displays the same way - could I be doing something wrong in my class?

Comment: I would do a process of elimination. Take out everything else of the XML and see how it looks. Work with it until it shows as you want, then add the other widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Set layout_width="wrap_content" not fill_parent, Then only you will get effect of the parent Layout gravity

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
```